# Creating checkboxes which include images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For the moment, my application only uses simple checkboxes with label. Our app designer wants us to change this into clickable images which works like checkbox.

Here an example:

[image]

I have no idea how to proceed, should i try to create a div (the square) filled with the image and then set my current checkbox in the bottom right corner of that div ?

Or maybe there's a simplier way to do it ?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=custom+checkboxes

Comment: "Accessible custom checkboxes" ;) http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/customInput/ Adding keyword *accessible* always leads to better semantics and often better code (and fewer results but that's not always a problem) EDIT: gasp the demo has some server problems atm

Comment: edit2: new link http://filamentgroup.github.io/checkboxradio/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/pwoojpv1/

HTML

```
<div class="check-img" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/35/Tux.svg/883px-Tux.svg.png" >
    <div class="check">&check;</div>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.check-img{
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
.check-img img{
    border:solid 2px gray;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.check{
    padding-left:5px;
    color:grey;

    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    background:grey;

    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
}
.check-img.checked img{
    border-color:orange;
}
.check-img.checked .check{
    background:orange;
    color:white;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".check-img").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("checked"); 
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks Joseph, that's exactly what i wanted ! mixing this with my angular JS code and it works fine !!

Answer (score 0):

Put the `<img>` inside a `<label>` element that's tied to the checkbox `<input>` element's `id`. So when you click on the label (the image), it's the same as clicking on the checkbox. Then wrap the `<input>` and the `<label>` inside a `<div>` so you can position the checkbox on the bottom right corner.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="checkbox1">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/rpUZ96Y.jpg" />
    </label>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="checkbox2">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/fKRGSmS.jpg" />
    </label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.container input {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skaj38uL/).